# openInputStream cause SecurityException : Permission Denial

Tags: java, android

I need help with this problem since I'm new to Android.

it crashes on the line where openInputStream() is called with error:

**E/ex: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary/MifareClassicTool/Dump-files/dump-file.dump from pid=19139, uid=10241 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()**

code :

uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary/MifareClassicTool/Dump-files/dump-file.dump

```
public static byte[] readUriRaw(Uri uri, Context context) {

    InputStream contentStream 
    if (uri == null || context == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {

           ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
            int perms =   Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION;
       context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, perms);

        contentStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

 
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException ex) {
        Log.e( "ex" , ex.toString());
        return null;
    }

    int len;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        while ((len = contentStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while reading from file.", e);
        return null;
    }

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Thank You in advance.

I need help with this problem.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: When you call `readUriRaw()`, are you doing so from the same activity instance where you originally got the `uri` value? https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: the same activity instance